# R language: how to separate data set?

Tags: r

I am a beginner, thanks for helping me.
R code to separate data into two groups. Subset of observations which have weight ≤ 10 units, and observations which have brain weight > 10 units. 
sounds quite simple but it is hard for me thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If the `weigth` values are in a column of a data frame (`dat`), you can use the following commands:

```
# subset with weight > 10 units
dat[dat$weight > 10, ]

# subset with weight <= 10 units
dat[dat$weight <= 10, ]
```

Alternatively, you can generate a list with two data frames:

```
split(dat, dat$weight > 10)
```